# Why is my NSMutableArray data for a UITableView getting lost by the time it gets used by tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath?

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

I have an `NSMutableArray *rows;` that I initialize and populate with data in `viewDidLoad`.  At that point, obviously, it has data.  In this case, three entries.

Then inside `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath` I'm calling `[rows objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]`.  However, at this point the `rows` array still contains three entries but the values of those entries are `0x00000000` instead of the original value (e.g. 'id' was `12345` but is now `0x00000000`.

It seems to me that somehow the value of the data in `rows` is getting emptied somewhere between `viewDidLoad` and `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath`.  What could be causing this?

**EDIT**

Here is the code:

`ViewController.m`:

```
@implementation ViewController

NSMutableArray *rows;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    rows = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [rows setArray:myData]; // myData is als an NSMutableArray populated from JSON data.
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{
    User *user = [rows objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; // At this point 'rows' contains three entries but the values are empty.
}

@end
```

**EDIT 2**

Here is the code after several suggested changes:

*ViewController.m*

```
@interface ViewController()
{
    NSMutableArray *rows;
}

@implementation ViewController
- (void)setRowsFromJSON
{
    NSString *fileContents = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:@"data.json" encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
    NSData *jsonData = [fileContents dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSArray *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];

    rows = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[jsonArray count]];
    User *user;

    for (NSDictionary *aUser in jsonArray) {
        user = [[User alloc] init];
        user.id = [aUser valueForKey:@"id"];
        user.name = [aUser valueForKey:@"name"];
        [rows addObject:user];
    }
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [self setRowsFromJSON];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{
    User *user = [rows objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; // At this point 'rows' contains three entries but the values are empty.
}

@end
```

Comment: `strong`, you released those objects, you changed those objects. without seeing code, I can only comment these.

Comment: Show the code for initializing `rows`.

Comment: Yeah, sounds like you somehow released the data you put into your array.  You kinda have to try to do that, so if you post come code it'll likely be obvious.

Comment: (Post the code that initializes the array.)

Comment: Uh, why do setArray vs just assigning the array?  `rows = myData;`.  No need for the alloc/init.

Comment: `rows = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:myData];`

Comment: (And you should really put the declaration of rows in your interface, not the implementation.  Not quite sure how ARC handles it the way you have it.)

Comment: @Darrell: hot licks says : `@property(strong)NSMutableArray *rows;` in your ViewController.h

Comment: What is the type of the elements in myData?  In your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is `user` nil or is `user` non-nil but its contents are nil?

Comment: @AnoopVaidya, no, if you make a property for `rows` put it in the .m file. No need to make it public.

Comment: @DarrellBrogdon How do you really declare `rows`? Is it really just sitting out like you show in your code? That's not right at all.

Comment: @maddy It was just out in the code like I showed.  How is it not right?  I've also tried the other suggestions (public property, private property, etc...) but I still get the same results.

Comment: Don't use setArray.  Either simply assign or use initWithArray or arrayWithArray.

Comment: The proper way to declare a private ivar is `@implementation ViewController { NSMutableArray *rows; }`. List all of your private ivars in the curly braces. When you stick a variable declaration like you have it, it is actually a file global variable, not an instance variable.

Comment: Updated the code to reflect my latest changes.

Comment: What does mean the comment "contains three entries but the values are empty"? What meens "empty" value? are they nil?

Comment: @Gabriel - I think with ARC, the system will SOMETIMES recognize when it's zapped an object in an array and will somehow flag the pointers.  Or perhaps the NSArray code can somehow check for zapped pointers.  The symptom has popped up a few times since ARC came into use, but it's never been well-characterized.

Comment: @Gabriel The value is '0x00000000' (XCode shows: (NSString *) 0x00000000). If that is the same is nil then, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

0x000000000 is nil. That means that row is pointing to nowhere.

I had the same problem running an app on iOS 5.1. The problem is you are supposing that viewDidLoad is always invoked before tableview:cellForRowAtIndexPath:. But that doesn't have to be that way. The first is a method of the view controller. The second is a method of the Table View Data Source. The fact that both are the same object is an accident.

In my case, the Table View Controller methods where invoked before viewDidLoad and then, after viewDidLoad, invoked again 'cause some modifications of properties of the View Table always make a reload.

Try to initialize in, for example, – numberOfSectionsInTableView:

Comment: This did it. Thanks!  Anybody know why this question was suggested for closing?  Is it not a valuable submission somehow?

Comment: @Darrell you're welcome. I don't know the reason of your -2 and the suggestion for closing. This question is of great value for the next dude will find this problem. I did lost a lot of hours to find the bug and I'm very pleased that I can help you now. Your question will help a lot of developers. I'm going to vote it up.